# #pragma acc host_data use_device() with complex variables

Tags: cuda, openacc

I need to pass to `#pragma acc host_data use_device()` an element of a vector of pointers of vectors:

```
static double *send_bufL[3];
static double *recv_bufL[3];

send_bufL[IDIR] = ARRAY_1D(NVAR*grid->nghost[IDIR]*nx2*nx3, double);
recv_bufL[IDIR] = ARRAY_1D(NVAR*grid->nghost[IDIR]*nx2*nx3, double);

#pragma acc enter data copyin(send_bufL[IDIR:1][:NVAR*grid->nghost[IDIR]*nx2*nx3], \
                              recv_bufL[IDIR:1][:NVAR*grid->nghost[IDIR]*nx2*nx3])

#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(4) present(d, grid, send_bufL[1:1][:NVAR*grid->nghost[JDIR]*nx1*nx3])
for (nv = 0; nv < NVAR; nv++){
for (k = kbeg; k <= kend;   k++){
for (i = ibeg; i <= iend;   i++){
for (j = 0;    j <  grid->nghost[JDIR]; j++){
   index = nv*nx3*nx1*grid->nghost[JDIR]+(k-kbeg)*nx1*grid->nghost[JDIR]+(i-ibeg)*grid->nghost[JDIR]+j;
   send_bufL[JDIR][index] = d->Vc[nv][k][jbeg+j][i];
}}}}

count = NVAR*nx3*nx2*nghost;
#pragma acc host_data use_device(send_bufL, recv_bufL)
{
MPI_Isend (send_bufL[IDIR], count, MPI_DOUBLE, nrnks[IDIR][0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
MPI_Irecv (recv_bufL[IDIR], count, MPI_DOUBLE, nrnks[IDIR][0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
}
```

Writing like this, with `send_bufL, recv_bufL` only I get:

*[marco-Inspiron-7501:41130:0:41130] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: invalid permissions for mapped object at address 0x7f7f4fafa608)*

[marco-Inspiron-7501:41131:0:41131] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: invalid permissions for mapped object at address 0x7fd697afa608)*

Trying to add dimensions I get compiling errors. What can I do?

I have to add the apparently, for some elements of the vector of pointers there's no need to use #pragma acc host_data use_device(). The compiler seems able to use the device buffers correctly. Anyway, for others elements this doesn't work and it uses host buffers, generating wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the "send_bufL[IDIR]" and "recv_bufL[IDIR]".  Since these are device pointers, dereferencing them on the host will give a seg fault.

I'm thinking that the best solution here would be to use temp pointers to the correct element in the buffers.  Something like:

```
double * sbtmp;
double * rbtmp;
...
sbtmp = send_bufL[IDIR];
rbtmp = recv_bufL[IDIR];

#pragma acc host_data use_device(sbtmp, rbtmp)
{
MPI_Isend (sbtmp, count, MPI_DOUBLE, nrnks[IDIR][0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
MPI_Irecv (rbtmp, count, MPI_DOUBLE, nrnks[IDIR][0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post a small reproducing example and I'll see if we can find a solution.